# How to change the driver's Expression to "var * 3 + var * 2"?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

I want to make a driver that combines the value of ShapeKey1 multiplied by 3 and the value of ShapeKey2 multiplied by 2.

I set the DriverSettings Type to Sum Values as shown in the image below.

And, I entered "var * 3" and "var * 2" in Expression.

[image]

However, an error message like the following image appears.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Change to scripted experession, (from sum variables) call your variables say sk1 and sk2 and make the expression `3 * sk1 + 2 * sk2`  Currently you are naming your variables `var * 3`  hence the error.

Comment: @batFINGER you can add this as an answer, this is the solution to the whole question

Comment: @RobertGützkow Been an advocate for a subexpression variable in drivers, (sim to as used in math surface)

Comment: @batFINGER Might be worth discussing on right-click select (if you haven't already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change driver type  to scripted expression, (from sum variables) call your variables say `sk1` and `sk2` and make the expression

```
3 * sk1 + 2 * sk2
```

or

```
sum(3 * sk1, 2 * sk2)
```

Currently you are typing an expression `var * 3`  into the name field of the variable hence the error.

To do this with sum variables driver type would need to add the sk1 variable 3 times and the sk2 variable twice. (all with unique names)

Comment: I think there's a typo, you might have pressed _enter_ after the first **`** character

Comment: Cheers went from inline eg between backticks to tabbed. Thanks.  Feel free to edit stuff like that.

Comment: I thought it'd be quicker to just tell you this time, since the answer is quite 'fresh' and my edit would be put on a queue